# Is it possible to set Photoshop keyboard shortcuts in GIMP?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-photoshop, gimp

Is there an option/configuration in GIMP to have its keyboard shortcuts like Photoshop's?

Comment: Which operating system? It should be possible with AutoHotkey, if you are using Windows. Also, can you describe the PS keyboard shortcuts you use and what they do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solution works on Linux, Windows and Mac using the standard GIMP download, no need for GIMPShop. I've used Photoshop for over 15 years and changing the keyboard shortcuts is absolutely essential for my sanity. GIMP is pretty much useless for me without this. Anyone who says that GIMP shouldn't work like Photoshop either hasn't relied on Photoshop in a production environment or is really really good at memorizing completely new keyboard shortcut sets for different applications. Don't fight muscle memory; just replace the shortcuts.

There is a settings file that you can replace with the one from the link below. It's very simple to do. It's not a perfect replacement but it's very close. Most recently tested with GIMP 2.6.12 but any newer versions should still be compatible.

http://epierce.freeshell.org/gimp/gimp_ps.php

*Edit:* A more complete alternative is this repository. Aside from updating the shortcuts, it also makes the interface more like Photoshop's.

https://github.com/doctormo/GimpPs

Comment: Note that in Windows 7 the save folder for this file is C:\Users\<Your Username>\.gimp-2.8

Answer (score -1):

I've never seen anything to replicate PS shortcuts for GIMP.  My recommendation would be to use the real deal.  I'd be interested to see that, although I am all about creative suite.

Adobe CS upgrades are 20% off till end of year form CS 2-4 to the new CS5.5.  After the end of year CS 2and3 wont be able to upgrade to the new CS'.  I just found this out, so just a little fyi.